# Solving homogenous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation 
$$f(n) = 2f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)$$
with initial conditions $f(0) = a, f(1) = b$. (here a and b are fixed, arbitrary integers).

I'm confused on how to approach this,  a and b are fixed, arbitrary integers.

Comment: I don't understand your answer in that , wouldn't we create a characteristic equation first ?

Comment: This is what I have down, this the polynomial $x^2-2x-1$.

Comment: wouldn't it be 2x^2 instead of x^2 because we have 2f(n-1)

Comment: The $2$ is in front of $x$. Since we have a second order linear recurrence relation, the term with the biggest index is associated with $x^2$, the second biggest index with $x$ and the least one with $1$. Indeed, notice that:
$$\begin{pmatrix}f_{n-1}\\f_{n}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}f_{n-2}\\f_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
What is the characteristic polynomial of the square matrix?

Comment: hmm never done characteristic equations with matrix so couldn't tell you :/

Comment: Then, I can only recommend you to read carefully your course notes and rehearse the method for solving such equations. The matrix trick is only used to make the proof. Alternatively, you can show that the set of solutions is a $2$-dimensional vector space and search for a solution of the form $r^{n},r^{-n}$, you will find and equation for $r$, which is $r^2-2r-1=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59210/discussion-between-m-jones-and-c-falcon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solve first the characteristic equation of the difference equation, which is:
$$ r^2 = 2r + 1 $$
resulting in solutions:
$$ r_1 = 1+\sqrt{2} \qquad r_2= 1-\sqrt{2} $$
The general solution to the difference equation is then:
$$ f(n)= c_1 (1+\sqrt{2})^n + c_2 (1-\sqrt{2})^n $$
Solving for the two coefficients, we use the initial conditions:
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= a & f(1) &= b \\
c_1+c_2 &= a & (1+\sqrt{2})c_1 + (1-\sqrt{2})c_2 &=  b
\end{align*}
$$ c_1 = \frac{(2-\sqrt{2})a + \sqrt{2} \, b}{4} \qquad c_2 = \frac{(2+\sqrt{2})a - \sqrt{2} \, b}{4} $$
So the difference equation with initial conditions:
$$ f(n) = 2 f(n-1) + f(n-2) \quad\qquad f(0)=a, f(1) = b $$
has solution:
$$ f(n) = \left( \frac{(2-\sqrt{2})a + \sqrt{2} \, b}{4} \right) (1+\sqrt{2})^n + \left( \frac{(2+\sqrt{2})a - \sqrt{2} \, b}{4} \right) (1-\sqrt{2})^n $$